# Trigger to UPDATE values of multiple rows after INSERT and DELETE

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two tables. You can see the schema here:

[image]

The **table2** has a foreign key referring to the id of **table1**.

The user is going to insert/remove an item in table2 with **table2.foreignkey_table1** and a **value**. Inside table2 there is already a set of values with table2.foreignkey_table1 equal to the one set by the user.

The trigger should update all the values when the new.value inserted by the user is lower than the ones in the tables. The action to be done is to increment the values after insertion, keeping the lower values the same.

*Example*:

Table2.foreignkey_table1 equal to 120 has in total 10 elements.

Each element has the following values: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

The user inserts a new value (3) in the Table2 with foreignkey_table1 equal to 120.

The trigger should compare all the values and move all the old.values from 3 to 10 adding +1. So the final list would be 1,2,3 (new value just inserted),4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11. From 4 to 11, they are the old values incremented.

The same thing should be done when the values are cancelled. For example, removing number 7, the trigger should decrement the higher numbers.

If the values is the highest in the list, nothing should be done.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Your scenario is a bit unusual. What is the purpose of table 1?

Comment: @Lennart table1 has other data connected to other tables. I just simplified table 1 removing other fields, because they are not involved in this kind of trigger.

Comment: *The trigger should compare all the values and move all the old.values from 3 to 10 adding +1.* Why so long? What does prevents simply to alter `NEW.value` from `3` to `1+MAX(value)` = `11`? the final result will be the same. And the same for deletion - simply update the record with maximal `value` (if deleted record have no maxvalue) and set its `value` to `OLD.value`...

Comment: Anycase you cannot update the table which fires the trigger in that trigger. I think it's better to use SPs for insert/update/delete instead of queries - you may realize a logic of any complexity in them, and triggers not needed.

Comment: @Akina I made it long because the item inserted by the user will have also other data to be pushed in the table1. 

It's required consistency because the NEW.value has a meaning of ordering for each item in table2.

Comment: You have skipped some ordering field which must stay in the same order? If so trigger cannot help you because it needs to update the table which's altering fires it. SP seems the only solution. But, if your data is ordered list in fact, think about altering the structure and use some store method specific for that kind of data.

Comment: @Akina Consider that the other table shouldn’t be ordered. I just need that Table2.value to be ordered depending on the input and delete as described before.